# How to make AWS Lambda stop execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have an `AWS` Lambda function does operations against `Kinesis Firehose`.
The function uses backoff mechanism. (which at this time I think wasting my computation time).

But anyway, in some point in my code, I would like to fail the execution.
What command should I use in order to make the execution stop?

P.s.
I found out that there are commands such as:

- `context.done()`
- `context.succeed()`
- `context.fail()`

I've got to tell you, I **could not** find any documentation about these commands in `AWS` documentation.

Comment: You couldn't find this page? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html If you want more help you will need to specify which NodeJS runtime version you are using.

Comment: This link answered SO many question I had. I could not find it. Thank you!  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I highly recommend that you switch to using the nodejs4.3 runtime if possible.  Starting October 2016 you will no longer be able to create lambda functions using the old runtime([source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/))

Comment: @JonathanSeed I am using this runtime version. Yet I've been using the old syntax without knowing. The above link is certainly the documentation that I've searched for.

Answer (score 3):

Those methods are available only for backward compatibility, since they were first introduced with Node.js v0.10.42. If you use NodeJS version 4.* or 6.*. Use the `callback()` function.

Check: [Using the Callback Parameter in Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback) for more information how to take advantage of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (probably not perfect, but it works for me)

```
time.sleep(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() / 1000)
```

The code is in Python, but I am sure you can apply the same logic using any other language. The idea is make my lambda function "fall asleep" for the remaining time of "retries".

The full example may loo like this:

```
... 
some code that processes logs from CloudWatch when my ECS container stops(job is finished) 
...

# Send an email notification
sns_client = client('sns')
                  sns_client.publish(
                      TopicArn=sns_topic,
                      Subject="ECS task success detected for container",
                      Message=json.dumps(detail)
                  )
                  # Make sure it was send only once, therefore 'sleep'
                  # untill lambda stops 'retries'
                  time.sleep(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() / 1000)
```

So, the email is send only once. I hope it helps!

Comment: This seems like it is going to have no impact on retry logic.  You should just `return` from your handler function when it is done. The OP is talking about 'wasting computation time' and this would make your lambda run for the full 15 minutes, every time.